# Dependencies (requirements) for setting up, testing, and installing a Python library

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, distutils

I'm writing a Python package to be distributed and installed via PyPi.org. There are plenty of examples out there, but I can't get my mind wrapped around the proper usage of the `install_requires`, `setup_requires`, and `tests_require` arguments in the call to `setup()`.

I know `install_requires` is the minimum set of dependencies for the library itself. This one is easy.

1. What is the difference (if there need be any) between `setup_requires` and `tests_require`?
2. What needs to go into each one if I want unit tests to run in a CI environment? And should unit tests run when the library gets installed?
3. When I set up a local virtualenv for developing and testing the library, which set of requires do I want installed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`setup_requires`:  **Don't use it.**  It was a failed experiment of setuptools. It has been obsoleted by [PEP517](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/) now (see deprecation note [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#package-requirement)) where the build system specifies build requirements declaratively in that config section, for example:

```
[build-system]  # in pyproject.toml
requires = ["setuptools >= 40.6.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

`tests_require`:  **Don't use it.**  It was a failed experiment of distutils. It has been obsoleted by projects such as `pytest` and `tox` (see deprecation note [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies)). Nobody runs their tests by calling `python setup.py test` anymore, and nobody wants their test dependencies downloaded into the project directory - they want them installed into the virtualenv instead:

```
[options.extras_require]  # in setup.cfg
test =
    pytest
    pytest-cov
```

So, to address the three points directly:

1. Both of those are cruft, omit them.
2. Specify your test requirements elsewhere (either in a setuptools "extras_require" or in a plain old `requirements_test.txt` file).  Yes, **tests should run against the installed code**.
3. When you set up a local virtualenv for developing and testing the library, both the local package and the test requirements should be installed, with e.g. `pip install -e ".[test]"`

Comment: are you using poetry? Is that where this is all going?

Comment: Not necessarily.  You can do all the above modern packaging practices, and reap the benefits, whilst still using setuptools.  But poetry is good too - it does a lot *more*, and stuff that you may or may not need, such as locking. It could be a better choice if you need to manage a deployment, but the question didn't mention about that.

Comment: Could someone please provide the canonical URL the the docs?

Comment: @guettli  See https://packaging.python.org/

Comment: I'm confused. You're saying that setuptools should treat test requirements as the same as any other dependency? What happens when your library requires a specific version of pytest or some unit test mock but another library has a version conflict? Now you can't install because of a TEST dependency? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: Those other libraries won't have their test dependencies installed, only yours will.  `extras_require` dependencies aren't installed unless you request them.